# jena sparql filter doen not give any output

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I have a rdf  file and I want to see the books which has amount less then 30.But it does not produce any output.

Here is the rdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

`<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:booktique ="http://www.w3.org/2001/booktique-rdf/3.0#">`

```
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/books/124">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Book"/>
        <booktique:bookID>124</booktique:bookID>
        <booktique:title>Geography</booktique:title>
        <booktique:price>10$</booktique:price>
        <booktique:author rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/authors/12999"/>
        <booktique:publisher rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/publishers/Mcgill"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/books/258">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Book"/>
        <booktique:bookID>258</booktique:bookID>
        <booktique:title>Physics</booktique:title>
        <booktique:price>20$</booktique:price>
        <booktique:author rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/authors/12999"/>
        <booktique:publisher rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/publishers/Swan"/>
    </rdf:Description>`

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/books/356">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Book"/>
        <booktique:bookID>356</booktique:bookID>
        <booktique:title>Phyton</booktique:title>
        <booktique:price>25$</booktique:price>
        <booktique:author rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/authors/13274"/>
        <booktique:publisher rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/publishers/Connoly"/>
    </rdf:Description>



    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/authors/12999">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Author"/>
        <booktique:name>James Brown</booktique:name>
        <booktique:authorID>12999</booktique:authorID>
        <booktique:e-mail>brown@gmail.com</booktique:e-mail>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/authors/13274">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Author"/>
        <booktique:name>Kelly Smith</booktique:name>
        <booktique:authorID>13274</booktique:authorID>
        <booktique:e-mail>smith@gmail.com</booktique:e-mail>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/publishers/Connoly">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Publisher"/>
        <booktique:name>Connoly</booktique:name>
        <booktique:address>US</booktique:address>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/publishers/Mcgill">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Publisher"/>
        <booktique:name>Mcgill</booktique:name>
        <booktique:address>UK</booktique:address>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/publishers/Swan">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/Publisher"/>
        <booktique:name>Swan</booktique:name>
        <booktique:address>FRA</booktique:address>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/sales/book/124">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/SalesOrder"/>
        <booktique:bookID rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/books/124"/>
        <booktique:amount>100</booktique:amount>

    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/sales/book/258">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/SalesOrder"/>
        <booktique:bookID rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/books/258"/>
        <booktique:amount>12</booktique:amount>

    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://booktique.com/sales/book/356">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/Resource/SalesOrder"/>
        <booktique:bookID rdf:resource="http://booktique.com/books/356"/>
        <booktique:amount>20</booktique:amount>

    </rdf:Description>
```

JENA Code :

```
static void sparqltest()
```

{

```
FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Test.class.getClassLoader());
Model model= FileManager.get().loadModel("booktique.rdf");
String queryString="PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/2001/booktique-rdf/3.0#>"+ 
"SELECT * WHERE {?s rdf:amount ?x."+
                    "FILTER (?x<30)}";
Query query= QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qexec=QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
```

`try {
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();while ( results.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
        Literal amount = soln.getLiteral("x");
        System.out.println(amount);
    }
}`

I checked the apache web site and many websites, whatever I tried I could not solve the problem.I have 2 source whose amount is less than 30.So how can I solve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that your query fails because of some missing spaces? There are no spaces around your string concatenations.

Comment: @marstan what you mean missing spaces?

Comment: Your query looks like this: `PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/2001/booktique-rdf/3.0#>SELECT * WHERE {?s rdf:amount ?x.FILTER (?x<30)}`. I'm not sure, but should there be a space between ´>´ and `S`, as well as between `.` and `F`?

Comment: It is not about space. I think it reads amount as a string not an integer.Because when I tried FILTER (?x =\"20\") it gives output 20.

Comment: Your original query uses an integer value as amount while your ontology only contains String literals as amount. You have to provide the datatype in your ontology, otherwise it's difficult to apply numerical comparison with SPARQL.

Comment: It's also strange that you use the prefix `rdf` in your query with a totally unusual namespace - this is technically not forbidden, but looks strange as usually the `rdf` prefix is the common prefix for the RDF namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<booktique:amount>12</booktique:amount>` is a string value with characters "1" and "2".  It is not a number.

You need to either:

1. In the data, give the property value a datatype.
2. Cast it to an integer in your query `xsd:integrer(?x) < 30`.